# Simplex Algorithm: basic solutions - optimal solution

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

Can someone explain to me the reason why the simplex algorithm proceeds
by only considering so-called basic solutions as candidates for the
optimal solution to an LP?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the [Fundamental Theorem of Linear Programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2065096/290189), which states that a LPP has an optimal solution if and only if it has an optimal basic solution.

Therefore, in a (dual) simplex algorithm, it suffices to explore *only* the basic solutions (which are finitely many) instead of the whole feasible region (which is uncountably many).